# Why isn't my div scrolling horizontally when adding multiple images?

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

I have an outer div, and inside of that, I have an inner div which contains a list of images.  When the images are wider than the outer div, I want to have it scroll horizontally, but instead, it just puts the image on the next line instead of expanding.  If I add many rows, the div does scroll vertically, but horizontally, it doesn't do it.  This happens on every browser I've tried - Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Safari.

Here is the css:

```
#grid-container   { left:33px; position:relative; width:300px; }
#grid   { width:310px; height:400px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 15px; }
#grid-container ul   { width:305px; }
#grid-container li   { float:left; list-style-type:none; padding:5px 15px 5px 15px; height:88px; text-align:center; }

.image-row   { float:left; margin-left: 10px; }
.grid-image   { height:50px; margin-left:-20px;  }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="grid"> 
    <div id="row1" class="image-row"> 
      <ul> 
        <li> 
          <img id="img1" class="grid-image" src="images/img1.jpg"> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <img id="img2" class="grid-image" src="images/img2.jpg"> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <img id="img3" class="grid-image" src="images/img3.jpg"> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <img id="img4" class="grid-image" src="images/img4.jpg"> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="image-row"> 
      <ul> 
        <li> 
          <img id="img5" class="grid-image" src="images/img5.jpg"> 
        </li>
        <li>
          <img id="img6" class="grid-image" src="images/img6.jpg"> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is img4 is showing on the second row (with img5 and img5 on the third row), even though it should on the first row and the `grid` div should scroll horizontally.  It does scroll vertically.  Can I force the div to expand?  If I remove the width from the grid div, I do get the horizontal scroll bar, but the image is still on the second row.

Comment: This would be easier to look at with valid markup.  You are missing opening <li> tags, and having invalidly commented style info does not help.  Include the valid CSS declarations you are using so someone can actually test this markup without rewriting it.  BTW -- I did try to test this and it actually seems to work OK in FF, so maybe you have some other issues or conflicting styles on your real page.

Comment: @bmoeskau - I updated the post with the css.  When you tested on FF, the div did scroll horizontally and show the images in one row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will this do? I simplified it somewhat.

CSS (you can remove the borders, they are just so you can see what is happening):

```
#grid-container {position: relative; width: 300px; height: 400px; overflow: auto; border: 1px red solid;}
#grid {border: 1px blue solid;}
#grid ul {height: 40px; list-style-type: none; white-space: nowrap; padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 1px green solid;}
#grid ul li {display: inline; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#grid ul li img {height: 50px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="grid-container">
 <div id="grid">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
   <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
   <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
   <li><img src="testimage.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a white-space:nowrap; on the UL and LI tags. You also need the LI elements to be display inline rather than floating them.

CSS:

```
#grid-container   { left:33px; position:relative; width:300px; }
#grid   { width:310px; height:400px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 15px; }
#grid-container ul   { width:305px; }
#grid-container li   { 
    display:inline;
   list-style-type:none; 
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px; 
    height:88px; 
    margin:0;
    text-align:center; 
}

ul, li{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="grid-container">
<div id="grid"> 
<div class="image-row"> 
  <ul> 
    <li> 
      <img id="img1" class="grid-image" src="test.jpg" /> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img2" class="grid-image" src="test.jpg" /> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img3" class="grid-image" src="test.jpg" /> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img4" class="grid-image" src="test.jpg" /> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="image-row"> 
  <ul> 
    <li> 
      <img id="img5" class="grid-image" src="test.jpg" /> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img id="img6" class="grid-image" src="test.jpg" /> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works in latest versions of IE, FF, Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#grid-container li { 
  display: inline;
  list-style-type:none; 
  padding:5px 15px 5px 15px; 
  height:88px; 
  text-align:center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the display and white-space elements, but I still have images going to multiple rows that should all be in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You're already on the right path: Your approach to set "float: left;" on the `<li>`s, in combination with setting "width: 305px" on the `<ul>`s should basically work to avoid float dropping.

However, a few things to check:

1. **Are 305px really enough?** (It must be at least as large as the combined width of the elements in row 1, including margins, paddings and borders) Try setting it to a much larger value. `overflow: auto` won't help, since the floats will always wrap instead of causing an overflow. Setting a large enough width works perfectly for me (at least in my own example).

Other things to try:

- Try it without floating ".image-row".
- Try setting a width on the images.
- You have the id "row1" twice in your HTML - that's invalid.

Comment: Setting a large width on the ul does work, but it leads to other issues - then the scroll bar appears, but it scrolls to that length, instead of the image widths.  I don't know the image widths beforehand - these are added dynamically, so it can lead to excess on the scroll (which isn't terrible), but the biggest problem is then if the images aren't very wide, the scroll bar will still show up which is bad. Also, the double row1 elements is a typo - that should be row1 and row2 (I've edited the question)

Comment: In that case, you have two options: a) Calculate the width on the server, and use it to dynamically generate the width on the <ul>. Or b) Not use floats, but inline formatting: Something like shipshape recommended. If that doesn't work for some reason, I have a slightly different version of that which I could post - but I think, shipshape's version should work.

Comment: My version will work, and you do not need to specify a width. I tested the code in Firefox, IE, Chrome, and Safari. I removed some of the elements and classes because they were unnecessary, but you can add them back in if you want, it will still work.

Comment: @shipshape: +1, but do we really need "position: relative;" at all (maybe for IE or so)?

Comment: No, you can take those out. The padding: 0 and margin: 0 are also not necessary, and of course you can remove the borders (I just included those so you could see the divs easily).

Comment: I have removed the extra "position: relative" declarations from my code.