# Scriptaculous Draggable/Droppable script not working properly when dragging into a scrolling div

Tags: drag-and-drop, overflow, scriptaculous, draggable, droppable

I am using the Scriptaculous [Draggable](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/draggable)/Droppable scripts and have a problem when dragging into a scrolling div.  I have the following layout (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414449/why-isnt-my-div-scrolling-horizontally-when-adding-multiple-images)):

```
#grid-container   { left:33px; position:relative; width:300px; }
#grid   { width:310px; height:400px; overflow:auto; margin-bottom: 15px; }
#grid-container ul   { width:400px; list-style-type:none; white-space: nowrap; }
#grid-container li   { display:inline; list-style-type:none; padding:5px 15px 5px 15px; height:88px; text-align:center }

.image-row   { margin-left: 10px; }
.grid-image   { height:50px; margin-left:-20px;  }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="grid-container">
  <div id="grid"> 
    <div id="row1" class="image-row"> 
      <ul> 
        <li><img id="img1" class="grid-image" src="images/img1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img id="img2" class="grid-image" src="images/img2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img id="img3" class="grid-image" src="images/img3.jpg"></li>
        <li><img id="img4" class="grid-image" src="images/img4.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="image-row"> 
      <ul> 
        <li><img id="img5" class="grid-image" src="images/img5.jpg"></li>
        <li><img id="img6" class="grid-image" src="images/img6.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have another div with draggable items, while all of the img elements are droppable.  This works very well for most cases, but when there are too many images for the grid and it has to scroll, I run into issues.  I can still drag/drop into most items in that div, but when I scroll down and then try to drag onto an item in the bottom of the list, it drops on the row that was at the bottom before I scrolled the div.

Even if I set the scroll attribute when creating the Draggable items, it will scroll the grid div, but not use the proper Droppable item.

Is there any way to make the Draggable items drop onto the proper Droppable element regardless of if the containing div is scrolled or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I found this [drag-drop-problem-in-scroll-div](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8887/tickets/59-drag-drop-problem-in-scroll-div) when having the same problem. Basically the solution is to add Position.includeScrollOffsets = true; to your code.

Hope it helps